# strcpy with destination pointer and return value

Tags: c

My plain C is a bit rusty, and I currently try to figure out why the first works and the second doesn't.

```
char *returnSomething(void) {
    char *s = (char *) malloc(5 + 1);
    strcpy(s, "Hello");

    return s;
}

void dontReturnSomething(char *dest) {
    char *s = (char *) malloc (5 + 1);
    strcpy(s, "Hello");

    dest = malloc(strlen(s) + 1);
    strcpy(dest, s);
    free(s);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char *first = returnSomething();
    char *second = NULL;
    dontReturnSomething(second);

    printf("first: %s | second: %s", first, second);
}
```

Isn't it basically doing the same thing?

Comment: You have one more strcpy than you need. You can malloc dest directly, and copy straight there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To return a pointer through a parameter you need a pointer to a pointer. Declare `dest` as `char **dest`.

```
void dontReturnSomething(char **dest) {
    char *str = "Hello";
    *dest = malloc(strlen(str) + 1);
    strcpy(*dest, str);
}
```

Call the function like this:

```
dontReturnSomething(&second);  // pass in address of second
```

Comment: Great! It works, I'am mildly embarrassed to forget that but happy. ;)
I assume functions like `strcpy` are iterating over the memory of the pointer and copying it into a new, am I right?

Comment: @Leandros `strcpy` is pretty much just `while (*dest++ = *src++) ;`. Note that this will stop when a `0` is copied to `*dest`.

Comment: Yeah, I thought of something like this. Great. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Leandros: `strcpy` iterates over memory *pointed to by* the pointer.

Answer (score 1):

To be more accurate, pointers to pointers are only necessary so long as, just as in the examples above, the memory is not allocated until after you enter the function. Just wanted to say this for anyone having pointer problems and thinks any passing of pointers always requires pointers to pointers to be passed.

For example, the below example works just fine.

```
void dontReturnSomething(int* testint)
{
    int test = 33;
    *testint = test;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    int *first = calloc(1,sizeof(int));

    printf("Before: %d\n", *first);
    dontReturnSomething(first);
    printf("After: %d\n", *first);
    return(1);
}
```

If you run it, you'll get 0 and 33 as expected. Of course the caveat to this is that you absolutely have to have memory allocated to the pointer being used. If you allocated memory for the pointer inside the function, then you will be assigning it a new address that would then have to be returned so that the address can persist. The below example also works just fine.

```
void dontReturnSomething(char* testchar)
{
    char* test = "Hello World!";
    strcpy(testchar,test);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    char *hello = NULL;
    hello = calloc(13, sizeof(char));

    printf("Before: %s\n", hello);
    dontReturnSomething(hello);
    printf("After: %s\n", hello);
    return(1);
}
```

Of course you will pretty much never know the size of a string, or more usually a buffer, ahead of time. I just think it's important to understand the subtleties of pointers.